# Selecting value from one excel sheet based on the values from another sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I've two sheets "Stock" and "Price" and I want to select supplier with min price and in case of tie i want to select supplier with maximum stock. Values that I want to get are in 3rd sheet i.e. Sup Selection. Sample data and desired result are under:

Sample Data and Desired Result

[image: Sample Data and Desired Result]

Any help would be appreciated.

I've used Min and Max functions but had no joy.

Answer (score 0):

**Perhaps** one could try if ***`Excel Formula`*** is an option, and *assuming if there is no **`Excel Constraints`** then*, using the following formula:

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>N3</kbd>

```
=LET(
     _stock, FILTER($B$3:$D$8,$M3=$A$3:$A$8),
     _maxSupStock, XLOOKUP(AGGREGATE(14,6,_stock/(_stock<>0)*(_stock<>""),1),_stock,$B$2:$D$2),
     _price, FILTER($H$3:$J$8,$M3=$G$3:$G$8),
     _minSupPrice, XLOOKUP(AGGREGATE(15,6,_price/(_price<>0)*(_price<>""),1),_price,$H$2:$J$2),
     IFERROR(IF(OR(MMULT(N(_price=TOCOL(_price)),{1;1;1})>1),_maxSupStock,_minSupPrice),"""NoStock"""))
```

---

The above formula needs to be filled down, however if you need a single dynamic array formula which spills then, using <kbd>MAP( )</kbd> as the <kbd>LAMBDA()</kbd> helper to iterate each cells in the range,

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>N3</kbd>

```
=MAP(M3:M8,LAMBDA(x,LET(
     _stock, FILTER($B$3:$D$8,x=$A$3:$A$8),
     _maxSupStock, XLOOKUP(AGGREGATE(14,6,_stock/(_stock<>0)*(_stock<>""),1),_stock,$B$2:$D$2),
     _price, FILTER($H$3:$J$8,x=$G$3:$G$8),
     _minSupPrice, XLOOKUP(AGGREGATE(15,6,_price/(_price<>0)*(_price<>""),1),_price,$H$2:$J$2),
     IFERROR(IF(OR(MMULT(N(_price=TOCOL(_price)),{1;1;1})>1),_maxSupStock,_minSupPrice),"""NoStock"""))))
```

---

Where:

- `_stock` *extracts the stock respective of each* `Pcode`

---

```
_stock, FILTER($B$3:$D$8,x=$A$3:$A$8),
```

---

- `_maxSupStock` *extracts the* `supplier` *based on max stock value*.

---

```
_maxSupStock, XLOOKUP(AGGREGATE(14,6,_stock/(_stock<>0)*(_stock<>""),1),_stock,$B$2:$D$2),
```

---

- `_price` *extracts the stock respective of each* `Pcode`

---

```
_price, FILTER($H$3:$J$8,x=$G$3:$G$8),
```

---

- `_minSupPrice` *extracts the* `supplier` *based on min price value*.

---

```
_minSupPrice, XLOOKUP(AGGREGATE(15,6,_price/(_price<>0)*(_price<>""),1),_price,$H$2:$J$2),
```

---

- ***Lastly***, the <kbd>MMULT()</kbd> *used to check whether there is a **tie** or not,* *if there is a **tie** then it brings the `_maxSupStock` **else** `_minSupPrice`*.

---

```
IFERROR(IF(OR(MMULT(N(_price=TOCOL(_price)),{1;1;1})>1),_maxSupStock,_minSupPrice),"""NoStock"""))))
```

---

Comment: I am using office 2010 and "filter" function is not available in that version. Thanks for taking time to look into it. Is there any solution available in office 2010 version?

Comment: @SajAbdullah sorry mate, you have not shown us what you have tried, still a solution has been given to you, do some research and then come up with what you have tried, people will help you out.

Comment: Mayukh Bhattacharya - thanks for your help mate. I am not an expert but I did try everything before coming down to this forum. I've used Min, Max, Vlookup and Index functions. I also used Countif function. With all these function I couldn't get dedired results.

Comment: Sorry I cant help you more, by now your query should have closed because you have not yet shown what you have tried and asking solutions with `VBA`, also my answer has clearly reminded about there is no excel constraints. You should read **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions)** & **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)** and don't forget to read **[Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/.../why-is-can-someone...)**